# How can I get previous row value in MySQL 5.7 grouping and ordering by

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have a dataset similar to this:

TABLE `TIMELINE`

| student_id | course_id | date | progress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 0.1 |
| 50 | 1 | 2022-01-02 | 0.3 |
| 50 | 1 | 2022-01-03 | 0.7 |
| 50 | 3 | 2022-01-01 | 0.2 |
| 50 | 3 | 2022-01-02 | 0.3 |
| 50 | 3 | 2022-01-03 | 0.9 |
| 73 | 2 | 2022-01-01 | 0.1 |
| 73 | 2 | 2022-01-02 | 0.4 |

This is already a query (so, a subquery in the final query) that group all the progress through the timestamp. I just grouped by `DATE` (and `student_id` and `course_id`) and got the `MAX(progress)` in order to have the granularity set to
`STUDENT - COURSE - DATE`.

I need to retrieve the progress for each day for each student for each course.

So, in that case:

| student_id | course_id | date | progress | progress_of_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 50 | 1 | 2022-01-02 | 0.3 | 0.2 |
| 50 | 1 | 2022-01-03 | 0.7 | 0.4 |
| .... | ..... | ..... | ..... | ..... |

The `progress of day` is the progress achieved that day minus progress achieved previous day

I managed to get this working using a simple JOIN with conditions:

```
timeline t1 LEFT JOIN timeline t2 
ON t1.student_id = t2.student_id 
AND t1.course_id = t2.course_id
AND t1.date > t2.date ## <---- THE SOLUTION BUT ALSO THE PROBLEM
```

So I could get `MAX(progress)` out of `t1` and `MAX(progress)` out of `t2` and simple subtract them

BUT this isn't performing well. Actually, I can't use it, the `timeline` table is massive and the only indexes we have is on `student_id`, so comparing the date between each row is insane. I managed to make this work with a few students and with LIMIT.

**Expected result: the same I would achieve with this, but performing well.**

I know maybe it is possible to do with @variables, but I don't know how to proceed.

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You need an additional left join to make sure there are no records for that student and course with a date between t1.date and t2.date.  But that just makes your performance problem worse.  You should have an index on (student_id,course_id,date).

Comment: What if I cannot change the indexes? Do you see any workaround? I cannot change anything on DB, primarily because I'm just a read_only user. My other alternative is throw this in a datalake with redshift, but this is a slowpace process

Comment: It is possible to do with variables, but setting variables in a select is deprecated in mysql 8 and may go away some day.  Can you not just subtract the previous value in your client, though?

Comment: You're likely to get someone showing how sooner if you include create table statements and insert statements for sample data.

Comment: Actually I'm using MySQL 5.7 (I'd use window function if I could). This should be a temporary solution, since the data is going to a datalake in AWS anyway. Ok, I'll include create table and insert as soon as I can. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT student_id,
       course_id,
       `date`,
       CASE WHEN @group = CONCAT(student_id, '-', course_id)
            THEN CAST(progress - @progress AS DECIMAL(2,1))
            ELSE progress
            END progress_of_day,
       @group := CONCAT(student_id, '-', course_id),
       @progress := progress progress
FROM timeline
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @group := '', @progress := 0 ) variables
ORDER BY student_id, course_id, `date`
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=650b940341e91b266fdd626bd4766566

Comment: Absolutely awesome. Work like a charm. It ran in 4 minutes (versus >90min using left join with date comparison)